# irb fails at startup to pause at my code

Tags: ruby

```
scripts joe$ irb -rdebug arbo.rb
/Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-    darwin16/continuation.bundle: warning: callcc is obsolete; use Fiber instead
Debug.rb
Emacs support available.

/Users/joe/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/init.rb:23:    unless @CONF[:PROMPT][@CONF[:PROMPT_MODE]]

   18      IRB.init_error
   19      IRB.parse_opts
   20      IRB.run_config
   21      IRB.load_modules
   22  
=> 23      unless @CONF[:PROMPT][@CONF[:PROMPT_MODE]]
   24        IRB.fail(UndefinedPromptMode, @CONF[:PROMPT_MODE])
   25      end
   26    end
   27
```

(rdb:1) `

It doesn't pause at the start of my program. It's pausing somewhere inside irb...

Comment: What are you trying to do here? This is dumping into the debugger.

Comment: I'm just trying to debug a simple ruby program, except the debugger isn't pausing in the context of my script. Pry goofs up also...

Answer (score 2):

`require "debug"` will stop execution after being required, as described [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/debug/rdoc/DEBUGGER__.html).

Since you're letting `irb` require it for you (`-rdebug`), it is stopping execution after the line that requires it: `IRB.load_modules`.

Also, you should not run your program with `irb` (or `pry`), but with `ruby`: `debug` will end up fighting `irb` for your standard input.

If you're using `pry`, use `binding.pry` instead of `require "debug"` (and still invoke your code with `ruby`, not `pry`), like this:

```
require "pry"

def say(word)
  binding.pry
  puts word
end

say "Hello"
```

(and run with `ruby file.rb`; or without `require "pry"`, invoke with `ruby -rpry file.rb`). In the same vein, you could use `byebug` with `byebug` instead of `binding.pry`.

The other part of the text you got shows that `debug` is written using continuations (for just one feature, `restart`), and continuations have been marked obsolete. Pry does not use continuations.